# SFTP with character encoding and line ending options

Tags: python

I am sending a file from one Linux VM to another Linux VM using python which is doing great. Files are sent successfully BUT before I send the file, I want to change the file encoding to "UTF-8" and line ending to "Unix/Linux". How to do that?

Below is the piece of code that is sending the file through sftp:

```
with pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=userName, password=passWord) as sftpVal:
    #print(sftpVal.listdir()) #list directories in sftp home
    sftpVal.put(source_file_path,'incoming/'+fileName) #(localPath, destinationPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to read the file contents, change them as you need, save them to a temp file, and send the temp file instead. For example:

```
with open('file_name.txt') as original_file, open('file_to_send.txt', 'w') as send_file:  # Open the original and prepared files
    content = original_file.read()
    content = content.replace('\r\n', '\n')  # Change the line endings
    content = content.encode('utf-8')  # Encode in UTF-8
    send_file.write(content)

# Do your file send here but with the prepared file instead.

os.remove('file_to_send.txt')  # Optional removal of temp file.
```